# First appearance of a weapon with the power of a nuclear bomb?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

### Atomic Bomb Predicted Before It's Time

Written literature that predated the atomic bomb made references to man creating a weapon that could set the sky on fire.

[H.G. Wells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells) book [The Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine) written in 1895 talked about the surface of the Earth being burned by man made fire. He later wrote [The World Set Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Set_Free) in 1914 and it clearly describes the atomic bomb.

### When Did A Nuclear Bomb First Appear?

The [Trinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_%28nuclear_test%29) nuclear test of the first atomic bomb was conducted on July 16, 1945. What is the date of the film that first featured a destructive weapon of on this kind of scale, and did that film predate the Trinity test?

I'm looking for the answer with the earliest film showing or discussing a bomb that can destroy a city.

[image: Big Bang]

Comment: This is a potential ___[list question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/176/list-of-movies-question-can-we-allow-it)___, unless it turns out there is _none_ or _only one_.

Comment: You could turn it into a [First Appearance](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) question. An answer to that question will automatically give you an answer to this one.

Comment: The idea of some apocalyptic weapon was certainly foreshadowed in literature before the bomb. H G Wells wrote more than one story where a war destroyed civilisation. The Time Machine, The Shape of Things To Come, for example. If these were made before 1945 as movies they might count. (Things To Come was a movie in 1936 but it isn't clear how explicit its portrayal of the weapons used in the war were).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, the earliest movie I could find, which features a nuclear holocaust (and the survivors) is a 1951 movie, **[Five](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043539/)**, which means that it did not predate **Trinity nuclear tests**

I find it very difficult to cross-validate this, though I referred to [List of Nuclear Holocaust Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_holocaust_fiction) on Wiki, to start with.

The [movie entry](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/27624/Five/articles.html) for articles on this movie, on TCM, speaks about this movie, as being the first to depict nuclear holocaust...

> It is remembered today as the first film to portray life after a
>   nuclear holocaust; later this theme was approached by major studios in
>   big-budget films such as The World, the Flesh and the Devil and On the
>   Beach (both 1959).

Answer (score 4):

The episode [Going Home](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_Home_(1944_film)) from the [Private Snafu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Snafu) series, completed by mid 1944, features a weapon which obliterated a Japanese island.

The movie was not released. The actual rationale is not known for sure, but the similarity between the fictional weapon and nuclear weapons is [listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_Home_(1944_film)#Release) as a possible reason that the movie wasn't released, and a [postscript](https://youtu.be/7YAnoT9Wqpo?t=3m49s) added to the movie gives that as the reason.

> Although made in May, this never saw release. It was shelved because
>   of the portrayal of a super-bomb in it. It was thought to be too close
>   a hint at the top secret atom bomb we were developing at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The movie [**The Day the Earth Stood Still(1951)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still_%281951_film%29) *discusses* atomic bombs.

In the movie, the alien *Klaatu* comes to earth on a goodwill mission. He has concerns that Earth might be destroyed by other alien civilizations, concerned for their own safety, in the wake of mankind inventing [Nuclear Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power).

Comment: Release date of **five** is April 25, 1951 which is earlier then release date of The Day the Earth Stood which is Still September 28, 1951

Comment: Somebody has an eye for details.... [chuckles]. Jokes apart, I would keep my answer here in spite of the 5 month gap between the two as I believe it somehow adds to the knowledge base.

Comment: Agreed...!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Destination Moon* (1950) was the second serious film about a scientifically plausible trip to the moon and helped start the 1950s science fiction movie trend. A low budget film *Rocketship X-M* was rushed into production and depicted a moon flight that missed and ended up on Mars (oops!).

On Mars they find ruins of an advanced society that are highly radioactive, suggesting that a long ago atomic war destroyed Martian civilization.

*Rocketship X-M* was released on 26 May 1950.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketship_X-M[1]

This precedes both *Five* and *The Day the Earth Stood Still*.